# With .htaccess file Server Gives error "500 : internal server error"

Tags: magento-1.7, error, server-setup, installation

I installed Fresh Magento in **Live Server with a subdomain** (shop.example.com)

And It given me error **500 : internal server error**

**But If i delete .htaccess** the site works properly

Without .htaccess file magento project won't be running.
So how to solve this ?

Answer (score 5):

You've clearly got an error in your `.htaccess` file.

If you check your Apache error log, you should see a pointer as to where the error is exactly.

Eg.

```
[Wed Mar 20 12:15:49 2013] [alert] [client 8.8.8.8] /home/chocoloo/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'faulty_line', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

There is also a chance the subdomain functionality you are using uses rewrites, in which case try setting

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: I added a .htaccess file in the **"Global Directory .htaccess"** area of cPanel It will used as global .htaccess of particular domain and its subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CGI mode for PHP (check phpinfo()), you must uncomment first two lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi    
AddHandler php5-cgi .php
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was lack of memory in PHP config.

Error was gone after adding to `.htaccess` line:

```
    php_value memory_limit 512M
```