# Internal Server Error (500) in Installation of magento 1.9.2.1 on aruba hosting

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, server-setup, file-permissions

I have uploaded all files to server (aruba.it) and saw below errors when browse the folder to install magento:

> Internal server error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@abc.com to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log

Other important details:

1. Magento works well if i install from scriptaculas.
2. But if i upload files from local then i get " Internal Server Error".
3. I have checked these links: [With .htaccess file Server Gives error "500 : internal server error"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1462/29175), https://minhnvt1.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/magento-solved-internal-server-error-500-error/. so dont suggest these.
4. magento version: 1.9.2.1
5. I tried by removing .htaccess too but that also didnt work.

> It seems to be basic question but It wasted a lot of time before i posted question here.
>
> This question will solve the pain of few developers who are facing challenges from aruba like hostings. Aruba ranks in top 10 in italy.

Comment: Have you looked at your apache log?

Comment: I have access to cpanel and but dont to apache log. How it can help me?

Comment: You might be able to pin point what is causing the 500 error

Comment: You can turn on errors in your index.php file, this may tell you something. If the server is cPanel then you can not use full permissions (666 and 777)

Comment: Problem with there server settings and it cant be sorted out from cpanel. I get help from support team to sorted out this.

Comment: .htaccess file's code need to commented. "Options +FollowSymLinks" on root folder. Error on other pages are sorted form support team.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your permission for Index.php from 664 to 644 in root directory

Do the same to Index.php in Downloader folder

Delete cache

Comment: I have already done these stufs. please read my question and i have posted what i already tried